# How to use numpy functions in numba

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba, matrix-inverse

I have to inverse my matrix. But I am getting an error. How to solve it?

```
@njit
def inv():
    x = [[1,2],[9,0]]
    inverted = np.linalg.inv(x)
    return x
inv()
```

> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> No implementation of function Function(<function inv at 0x7f1ce02abb90>) found for signature:
>
> inv(list(list(int64)<iv=None>)<iv=None>)
>
> There are 2 candidate implementations:
> - Of which 2 did not match due to:
> Overload in function 'inv_impl': File: numba/np/linalg.py: Line 833.
> With argument(s): '(list(list(int64)<iv=None>)<iv=None>)':
> Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
> TypingError: np.linalg.inv() only supported for array types
> raised from /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/np/linalg.py:767
>
> During: resolving callee type: Function(<function inv at 0x7f1ce02abb90>)
> During: typing of call at  (4)
>
>
> File "", line 4:
> def inv():
>
> x = [[1,2],[9,0]]
>    inverted = np.linalg.inv(x)

Comment: I'm no jit expert but I doubt you would get any speed benefits from just wrapping a numpy function. Or is this just a simplified example?

Comment: @mcsoini you are right. it is simplified

Comment: I haven't tried, but `TypingError: np.linalg.inv() only supported for array types` might give it away. Try `x = np.array([[1,2],[9,0]])`

Comment: @mcsoini no it doesn't work. Numba doesn't support numpy array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a `np.array` of `float` or `complex` dtype, not some `list` with `int`:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np  

@jit(nopython=True)
def inv():
    x = np.array([[1,2],[9,0]], dtype=np.float64) # explicitly specify float64 dtype
    # x = np.array([[1.,2.],[9.,0.]]) # or just add floating points
    inverted = np.linalg.inv(x)
    return x
inv()
```

see the [linear algebra supported numpy features](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#functions) in numba.

Comment: Yeah, I know it works, when I send from outside. But I need that it should work from the inside. So that's why I put the matrix inside the function. numpy array doesn't work inside the jit function. How to do it from inside?

Comment: Just initialize  `x` exactly as I did from inside the function, you need to use `float64` dtype. See the edited answer.

Comment: Very interesting. Why it doesn't work with integers?

Comment: I am not sure exactly why, but my guess is that usually `numpy` is much more flexible than `numba` and will automatically cast `int` to `float64` internally when calling `inv`, you can check the source to be sure. My advice to you is the following: when mixing `numba` and `numpy`, always strictly refer to the link I gave you in the answer above, this page provides all the informations you need to make `njit`ted functions run :)